# jQuery .resize() won't trigger function

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I've written a function to resize the menu blocks on my website. Then I set the function to execute on the window being loaded and on the window being resized. It works as expected with `.load()` but it doesn't have any effect at all on `.resize()`. I can see that it function is being called, because it hits the alert, but it doesn't do the actual resizing from the function.

I know that the function works, because if you refresh the window, it triggers the function and the menu blocks resize. I also know that the `.resize()` and the function are being reached, because it triggers the alerts when the window is resized, but the function doesn't actually resize the divs.

I have tried it using `.bind('resize', function () {})`, `$(window).onresize = changeWidth();` and using `setInterval(function () {}, 300)` and then checked to see if the window size had changed and they all have the same result.

My function looks like this:

```js
function changeWidth() {
  alert('resized');
  var widestBlock = 0;
  $('.menu-block').each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > widestBlock) {
      widestBlock = $(this).width();
    }
  });

  $('.menu-block').each(function() {
    $(this).width(widestBlock);
  });
}
```

And then I trigger the function with `.load()` and `.resize()`

```js
$(window).load(changeWidth());
$(window).resize(function() {
  changeWidth();
  alert('hola');
});
```

Comment: How do you actually resize your window!? This an odd issue.

Comment: `$(window).load(changeWidth());` should be `$(window).load(changeWidth);`, otherwise you are calling `changeWidth` immediately and passing its return value to `.load`

Comment: Or better yet, use `$(changeWidth);` to ensure it executes once the DOM is ready.

Comment: @AdamAzad I am simply changing the size of my browser window. Although if you look at it on smaller devices it still adjusts the sizes. It's only on window resizing that it doesn't work.

Comment: @csum You're right and I made that change, but weirdly it seems to work either way. I'm using the $(window) instead of $(document), because I am rendering the menu with an ajax request, so I need to wait for the window to finish loading

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE: **MAKING A MENU COMPONENT**
>
> We need to have a menu where their items have the same width, calculated on the widest item or the window width.

```js
function MenuCtrl($) {
  var self = this;

  // set it to true if you want to calculate on the available width      
  self.basedOnWindowWidth = false;

  self.selector = '#resizableMenu';
  self.menu = $(self.selector);
  self.meta = null;
  
  self.updateItemsWidth = function() {
    var id = 'resizableMenuStyle';
    var style = $('#' + id);
    
    if(style.length < 1) {
      style = $('<style />', {
        id: id
      }).appendTo('head');
    }
    
    style.html(self.selector + ' a { width: '+ self.meta.maxWidth +'px; }');
    return self;
  };
  
  self.study = function studyMenu() {
    var res = {
      itemsCount: 0,
      maxWidth: 0,
      width: 0,
      height: 0
    };
    
    var items = self.menu.find('> li');
    
    res.itemsCount = items.length;
    res.width = self.menu.outerWidth();
    res.height = self.menu.outerHeight();
    
    if(self.basedOnWindowWidth) {
      res.maxWidth = window.innerWidth;
    } else {
      items.each(function(index, item) {
        width = $(item).width();
      
        (res.maxWidth > width) || (res.maxWidth = width);
      });
    }
      

    self.meta = res;
    return self;
  };
  
  self.study().updateItemsWidth();
  
  var semaphore;
  $(window).resize(function(event) {
    window.clearTimeout(semaphore);
    
    semaphore = window.setTimeout(function() {
      return $
        .when(console.count('Window Resize End'))
        .then(function() {
          return self.study();
        })
        .then(function() {
          return console.log('menu metadata after resizing', self.meta);
        })
        .then(function() {
          self.updateItemsWidth();
        })
      ;
    }, 200);
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(MenuCtrl);
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body, .nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;

  background: red;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em 1.5em;
  background: yellow;
  
  transition: 400ms width linear;
}
.nav li {
  margin: .5em 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="resizableMenu" class="nav nav-resizable">
  <li><a href="#">1 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">6 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">7 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">8 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">9 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">10 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">11 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">12 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">13 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">14 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">15 - lorem Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">16 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">17 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">18 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">19 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">20 - lorem Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">21 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">22 - lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">23 - lorem</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

Try to exec your fn on the resizeEnd event!

```js
function resizeView() {
  // do what you want
  console.count('Called resizeView');

}

var semaphore;
jQuery(window).load(resizeView).resize(function(event) {
  window.clearTimeout(semaphore);
  
  semaphore = window.setTimeout(resizeView, 200);
};
```

Comment: $Hitmands, thanks for the answer, I tried a few variations, but I wasn't able to get it to work. Also, how are you declaring the ```semaphore``` variable?

Comment: Hey @CascadiaJS, there was a mistake, we need to declare the variable outside from the scope of that function.
However, can you please post a detailed explanation of what are you looking for?
I will help you, but I need more information :)

Comment: Thanks again, I'll try and explain better: I have a menu with divs that contain menu titles of different lengths, which gives them different widths, so I wrote a function to check the width of the widest block and make all of the blocks that width. This works the way I want it to when it is triggered on the ```$(window).load()``` but when I try to use some variation of ```$(window).load()``` the changeWidth function isn't triggered, even though it will trigger alerts and console logs from within the function.

Answer (score 0):

Following the way you have started You can try to do this:

```
function changeWidth() {
  var widestBlock = 0;
  $('.menu-block').each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > widestBlock) {
      widestBlock = $(this).width();
      console.log(widestBlock)
    }
  });

  $('.menu-block').each(function() {
    $(this).width(widestBlock);
  });
}


$(window).load(function(){
  changeWidth();
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
      changeWidth();

    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it turns out it was the .width() causing problems for some reason. I'll paste the answer in my question above